# Access WCF service through ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, basichttpbinding

I have a WCF service which I would like to access using ASP.NET. The binding used in the WCF service is **basicHttpBinding**. How may I do it? Any examples will be really appreciated.

Will it work fine if I create a proxy from the **svcutil.exe** and then use that class in an ASP.NET page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a service reference in your asp.net website project (here named ServiceReference1) and then here's your client:

```
var serviceClient = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
```